# Operators not being appended in infix to postfix conversion

Tags: java, stack, calculator, postfix-notation, infix-notation

**Update:** Fixed the silly ".equals()" mistakes.
        However, my program is getting stuck in the last `while` loop in `infix2postfix()`.
        Why isn't the stack of operators emptying out?

**Original:** I am currently trying to make an infix to postfix converter. However, the operators are not being appended to the postfix string.

I've been looking at my code for a while and I think it may just need a fresh pair of eyes.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the `else if`, for the operators?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class old{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //File to scan
        File file = new File("input.infix");
        //Scanner for the file
        Scanner scanf = null;
        try {
            scanf = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("File Not Found: 'input.infix'");
        }

        //Convert each line of Infix to Postfix
        while(scanf.hasNextLine()){
            //Store Postfix and its Evaluation
            String postfix;
            int postEval;
            //Convert Infix to Postfix
            postfix = infix2postfix(scanf.nextLine());
            //Evaluate Postfix
            postEval = evalPostfix(postfix);
            //Print the Postfix Equation and Evaluation
            System.out.println(postfix + " = " + postEval);
        }
    }
    //Takes Line of File (each Infix) as a String and Returns a postfix String
    public static String infix2postfix(String infix){
        //Postfix String to Return
        String postfix = "";
        //Store Equation in Stack
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        //Append a Right Parentheses to the Input Expression
        infix = infix + " " + ")";
        //Push a Left Parentheses on to the Stack
        stack.push("(");
        //Split the Infix String into String Tokens
        String[] tokens = infix.split("\\s+");
        //Starting at the first Token, for each token
        for(int t = 0; t < tokens.length; t++){
            //System.out.println(stack);
            String token = tokens[t];
            try{
                Integer.parseInt(token);
                postfix += token + " ";
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                //If "(" -- Push to stack
                if(token.equals("(")){
                    stack.push(tokens[t]);
                }//If ")" -- Pop Operators from stack and Append them to postfix
                else if(token.equals(")")){
                    //Do this until a "(" is reached
                    while(!stack.peek().toString().equals("(") && !stack.isEmpty()){
                        postfix += " " + stack.pop();
                    }
                    stack.pop();    //Pop the "("
                }//If Operator -- Determine Precedence
                else if(token.equals("+") || token.equals("-") || token.equals("*") ||token.equals("/") || token.equals("%")){
                    String element = stack.peek().toString();  //Pass stack element as String
                    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
                        //INFINITE LOOP
                        boolean gte = opPrec(element, token);   //Is element >= token
                        if(gte){
                            postfix += " " + stack.pop();
                        }
                    }
                    stack.push(token);
                }
            }
        }

        return postfix;
    }

    private static boolean opPrec(String element, String token) {
        //Greater than or Equal to
        boolean gte = false;
        //Precedence Values
        int sVal = 0;
        int tVal = 0;
        //Stack Value
        if(element.equals("+") || element.equals("-")){
            sVal = 1;
        }
        else if(element.equals("*") || element.equals("/") || element.equals("%")){
            sVal = 2;
        }
        //Token Value
        if(token.equals("+") || token.equals("-")){
            tVal = 1;
        }
        else if(token.equals("*") || token.equals("/") || token.equals("%")){
            tVal = 2;
        }
        //Evaluate Precedence
        if(sVal >= tVal){
            gte = true;
        }
        //System.out.println(gte);
        return gte;
    }

    //Takes Postfix String, Parses it, Evaluates it, Returns postEval
    public static int evalPostfix(String postfix){
        //Evaluation of Equation to Return
        int eval = 0;
        //NOT YET CONSTRUCTED
        return eval;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings using '=='. Use .equals(...) for String comparisons in Java. Eg.

```
           if(token == "("){
```

Should be:

```
           if(token.equals("(")){
```

I believe this will solve your problem. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)